# Using Jenkins with Black Duck Hub

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed Jenkins, download Black Duck Hub plugin(v 4.0.1).

I followed next steps. Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins go to the section Black Duck Hub, paste server url, credentials and when I tested the connection got a error.

> com.blackducksoftware.integration.hub.rest.exception.IntegrationRestException: Connection Error: 401 : 401
>   com.blackducksoftware.integration.hub.rest.exception.IntegrationRestException: Connection Error: 401 : 401
>       at com.blackducksoftware.integration.hub.rest.CredentialsRestConnection.clientAuthenticate(CredentialsRestConnection.java:93)
>       at com.blackducksoftware.integration.hub.rest.RestConnection.connect(RestConnection.java:133)
>       at com.blackducksoftware.integration.hub.jenkins.PostBuildScanDescriptor.doTestConnection(PostBuildScanDescriptor.java:476)
>       at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>       at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>       at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>       at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>       at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.lambda$scheduleNext$0(BoundedExecutorService.java:80)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means an unauthorized request.
Make sure the blackduck server url is correct (http**s** maybe?) and that your credentials are working (try login using them through black duck dashboard)